# Proving a fact about complex numbers

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

How to prove the following:

> For any complex numbers $z_1,...,z_n$, there exists a subset $E$ of $\{1,...,n\}$ s.t.
>
> $$\left| {\sum\limits_{j \in E} {{z_j}} } \right| \geqslant \frac{1}{6}\sum\limits_{j = 1}^n {\left| {{z_j}} \right|} $$

Comment: Care to show your attempts at a solution?

Comment: The above is not a duplicate, because (1) that previous question doesn't ask for how to solve it, but for an explanation of a part of a solution, and (2) this particular problem is much easier than the tighter bound in the Rudin question.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Divy the plane up into three pieces in a clever way. This will divy $\{1,2,\dot,n\}$ into sets $E_1,E_2,E_3$ based on where the $z_i$ are located. Pick the $E_i$ to maximize $\sum_{j\in E_i} |z_i|$ and call it $E$. Then you'll see that:

$$\sum_{i\in E}|z_i| \geq \frac{1}{3}\sum_{i=1}^{n} |z_i|$$

Now if you picked your three pieces cleverly, you will have:

$$\left|\sum_{i\in E}z_i\right|\geq \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i\in E} |z_i|$$

Comment: Could you make it more specific?

Comment: Given the amount of effort you've given in your question?

Comment: So just consider dividing the plane into three equal parts and then it is done, am I take it right?

Comment: You'll need to do it cleverly, so you can deduce the second inequality in my post.

Comment: Understood. I will try it. Thanks for your ideas!